# Can someone please tell me what the icon on the left means

Tags: notification-icons

[image]

After updating my Samsung Galaxy s8+ software the icon on the left appeared. Anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 4):

It's the new data saving icon in Android 8 Oreo on Samsung devices.

Try turning off "Data Saving" and it'll disappear.

Source: [XDA Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s8/help/triangle-icon-arrows-mean-t3728195)